# Localhost not working while using bottle python

Tags: python, localhost, bottle, web-frameworks

Localhost throwing an error 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED', I am setting up a localhost to display simple Hello world. However, localhost isn't working.

I am working on displaying all my data on the localhost, it was working perfectly fine, then all of sudden it stopped working. I have not installed any new program or anything. I tried using different ports yet I yet nothing .

```
from bottle import route, run, request, post, get, template
@route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__== '__main__':
    run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

This is supposed to display Hello World on my localhost. However, when I run the program nothing happens. I get the error above when I try to access it through the browser but when I run the program nothing happens in the console. Usually, you would get the message of local host is running you can terminate using ctrl+c

Comment: In programming nothing happens *suddenly*. You just haven't found the root cause yet.

Comment: How do you manage your ports ?

Comment: @rbcvl what do you mean?

Comment: Sounds like your previous run of the app is still "on" maybe?  Have you rebooted and tried?

Comment: @eatmeimadanish yes I have still the same issue stands, I even tried creating different project after the reboot.

Comment: Are you typing http://localhost:8080 or http://127.0.0.1:8080 ?

Comment: yea, tried both they don't work. I tried different ports too, it still doesn't work. I tried ping from cmd it responds perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the loop back address instead.  If you use gevent, then use `0.0.0.0`

```
from bottle import route, run, request, post, get, template
@route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__== '__main__':
    run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I typed `host='localhost'` instead of the whole IP.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30038362)

Comment: This seems to be a comment on the previous answer. It’s clearly not a new answer as the OP’s code _already_ uses `host='localhost'`.